# Why does it say that the variable was not initialised?

Tags: java

```
package mmm;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hi{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int num1, num2, result, choice;
        Scanner abhi = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("You Have The Following Choices:");
        System.out.println("1. Addition");
        System.out.println("2. Subtraction");
        System.out.println("3. Multiplication");
        System.out.println("4. Division ");

        choice = abhi.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter The First Number");
        num1 = abhi.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter The Second Number");
        num2 = abhi.nextInt();
        switch(choice){
        case 1:
            result = num1 + num2;
        break;
        case 2:
            result = num1 - num2;
        break;
        case 3:
            result = num1 * num2;
        break;
        case 4:
            result = num1 / num2;
        break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error");


        }
        System.out.println("The Result Is "+result);



    }
}
```

It says `result` was not initialised; whereas I initialised it.
Where did I basically go wrong? I declared the variable type and all and did everything I could. I am a noob, so, pardon my silly questions and queries.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: which variable was not assigned? can you show us the output?

Comment: What is the value of `result` in `System.out.println("The Result Is "+result);` if your `switch` hits the default case?

Comment: local variables don't take default values and you are not initializing it in default case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go in the default case of your switch, the `result` variable will have received nothing when trying to print it.

You will have to give it a default value either before going in your switch, or inside your `default` case.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables don't have a default value. You have to initialize the variables `int num1, num2, result, choice;` with one, if you want to access them.

Comment: In the posted code, only `result` can ever be accessed without having been assigned a value (as per @bradimus comment).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by comments.

The variable `result` is only gets value in cases `choice` was `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`. So, not all code paths lead to the variable `result` being assigned to a value.

However, all code paths lead to `System.out.println("The Result Is "+result);`.

You either have to assign a value to `result` in the `default` case, or initialize it with a value at the when declaring it. . .

Answer (score 0):

Change you first line in the main method as following:

```
int num1, num2, result, choice = 0;
```